# How to compare file permissions between two files?

Tags: bash, permissions, chmod

I'm trying to script a check to make sure two files have the same permissions.  There are several ways to think about permissions, the most basic being a hex value (e.g. `777`).  How can I compare the permissions on two different regular files in bash?

```
touch a b
chmod 777 a
# What can I use to get the `777` value property from `a`?
if a.perms == b.perms; then
  echo "File permissions match!"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stat`, with the right options, seems to provide a way to compare this property, but not to an arbitrary permissions argument (e.g. `777` or `+x`).  For that you'll want to choose the appropriate representation (e.g. `%A` or `%a`).  See more in the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/stat.1.html).

```
$ echo "$(stat -c '%a' a)"
777
```

```
perms_a="$(stat -c '%a' a)"
perms_b="$(stat -c '%a' b)"
if [ ${perms_a} = ${perms_b} ]; then
  echo "Permissions match!"
else
  echo "NO match."
fi
```

Comment: Replace `==` with `=` if you want to be POSIX compliant.